# Linking external login fails - Uprotected Ticket

Tags: identityserver4

I have built a solution based on Identity Server 4 for a customer, and almost everything works great :) However, I have one problem that is not consistent; sometimes it works, and sometimes it fails. This is when a user is logged in, accesses the settings page and then tries to link an external login, (e.g. Facebook or Google) to the account.

The controller gets called, and the following code is executed without any problem:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LinkLogin(string provider, string cancelUrl = null)
    {
        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await this.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
        var redirectUrl = this.Url.Action(nameof(this.LinkLoginCallback));

        var properties = this.signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(
            provider,
            redirectUrl,
            this.userManager.GetUserId(this.User));
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
    }
```

But the callback is not always called, and when it fails I get the following error in the logs:

> Identity.Application was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more that one server in play? If so it’s neccessary for them to use the same data protection keys and thus must have a shared data protection store.

Comment: I only have one server (one instance in Auzre). I'm also have the same problem om may developer machine, but there it works some times and some times not. I'ts never working in Azure ..

Comment: First thing I’d do is check out the code that throws that exception (it’s all on github) and work back from there.